# hibernate уникальный результат

Tags: java, hibernate

Есть веб-приложение на БД Oracle с ORM Hibernate, проблема такова: при аутентификации пользователя вызывается метод чтения из DAO:

```
public Customer readByUsername(String username) {
    Customer customer=null;
    session=HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    try{
        transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        String queryString = "from Customer where username= :username";
        Query query=session.createQuery(queryString);
        query.setParameter("username",username);
        customer= (Customer) query.uniqueResult();
    }catch (RuntimeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        session.flush();
        session.close();
    }
    return  customer;
}
```

На строке `customer= (Customer) query.uniqueResult()`
выскакивает исключение **NonUniqueResultException: query did not return a unique result: 6**

В ручную проверил в БД там пользователь с таким **username** всего один.

Возможно проблема в том что я до этого неоднократно добавлял и удалял такого же пользователя и оно где-то закешировалось

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была решена. Когда производились изменения в БД через SQL Developer не был сделан финальный commit, соответственно hibernate видел куда больше одной и той же сущности.